# select rows having same column value

Tags: oracle, group-by

I am trying to form a query for following scenario

if my table is

```
signature |   id  | operation

abc       |    1  |   1234 

xyz       |    1  |    1234

pqr       |    2  |    1234
```

then my output should be

```
signature |  id

abc       |  1

xyz       |  1
```

i.e. rows having same value in a particular column.

i have formed query like

```
select signature,id 
from tablename 
where operation = '1234' 
group by signature,id 
having count(*) >0;
```

but this is returning everything including xyz | 1 also.

Can someone suggest me correct query?

Comment: why there is group by for signature?

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want?

Comment: i tried without signature for groupby but it gives me following error    ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: explain what you want..

Comment: i want to have signatures which have operation = '1234' and same id

Comment: So its not mysql its oracle and you tagged the question with mysql

Comment: sorry about that. changed it.

Comment: You're expecting to exclude "xyz | 1" but there's nothing telling him to exclude that one. When you exclude, you also must have a basis for exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT signature,COUNT(id) FROM table_name WHERE operation = '1234' GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: DO you have any idea that its not valid group by expression in oracle ?

Comment: its not valid in oracle.  Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression  and how does consider condition of same column value?

Comment: its still not valid. in oracle you need to add both signature and id in group by and that's what is bothering me.

Comment: You need to group by signature instead of id.

Comment: Are you for real? Come on guys "id" meant to be unique, how could it be grouped?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this and it might be overly complicated but I THINK this will work:

`SELECT Signature, ID from tablename WHERE ID in( SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ID, COUNT(*) as NumRecords from tablename GROUP BY ID HAVING NumRecords > 1)))`

Comment: I wrote this for the original MYSQL tag - no idea if this works for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

We need to apply PARTITION on ID column as follows,

SELECT Result.[signature], Result.ID ,
ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY Result.ID ORDER BY Result.ID) AS [RowNum]
INTO #TempResult
FROM table_name  AS Result
GROUP BY Result.[signature], Result.ID

SELECT Result.[signature], Result.ID
FROM #TempResult  AS Result
where Result.[RowNum] = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `where exists` for an alternative to `group by`

```
select 
signature,
id 
from tablename t1 
where exists (
   select * from tablename t2 
   where t1.id = t2.id 
   and t1.signature != t2.signature 
   and t1.operation = 1234 
);
```

Comment: this also returns evverything. i.e. all 3 entries .

Comment: Not sure what you are getting check the fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53213a/2